# Apply colspan to dropdown list in html 5

Tags: html, html-table

I have crated table and want to apply the colspan property of column to the drop down list in HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
<select >
 <option>item 1</option>
 <option>item 2</option>
 <option>item 3</option>
 <option>item 4</option>
</select>
</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Result is:
[image]

Why drop down list in the 2nd row and 1st column is not taking width of column.
I have given colspan of column to "2". Item placed inside the column should take width of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `select` a `width:100%`

Right now its just taking up the minimum amount of space it needs based on the words inside

As @Nelson also stated If you look at the screenshot carefully, the table cell IS two columns wide, but the dropdown isn't the full width of the cell.

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/QjaNYV

Comment: If you look at the screenshot carefully, the table **cell** IS two columns wide, but the dropdown isn't the full width of the cell.